# Getting notified when Windows connects to a network

Tags: java, windows, networking, notifications, java-native-interface

Is there any way to be notified by windows OS when a new connection is available, in a Java program (using JNI)?
At the moment the only way I have to check this is by polling a function that tries to download a webpage. If the download success and no exception is thrown, then I can guess there is Internet connectivity.

However, a better solution could be this one:

1. On program start, check Internet connectivity
2. If no internet connection is available, "register" for windows network notification and WAIT()
3. User connects to Internet, Windows os notifies the Java machine=> the threads wakes up
4. Do some stuff....

Comment: Seems related to [Notification of when a network interface is ready on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4546878/291641) although that is not Java. The [WM_DEVICECHANGE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363480(v=vs.85).aspx) message would also seem a likely candidate for having the system notify you about this.

Comment: Yes, but how to listen to windows messages? I bet there is some JNI library for do that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following do a ping, less costly than downloading a page, and you can change the time out:

```
InetAddress.getByName( "stackoverflow.com" ).isReachable( 4000 )
```

Placed into a thread loop, at low priority:

```
while( ! InetAddress.getByName( "stackoverflow.com" ).isReachable( 4000 )) {
   Thread.slepp( 1000L );
}
```

I haven't better.

`InetAddress.isReachable` documentation:

> Test whether that address is reachable. Best effort is made by the
>   implementation to try to reach the host, but firewalls and server
>   configuration may block requests resulting in a unreachable status
>   while some specific ports may be accessible. A typical implementation
>   will use ICMP ECHO REQUESTs if the privilege can be obtained,
>   otherwise it will try to establish a TCP connection on port 7 (Echo)
>   of the destination host.

Comment: Sometimes firewalls are configured to block ICMP messages.

Comment: There are known issues with `isReachable()`: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2448666/694576

Comment: @ShashankKadne The method only uses ICMP in the exceptional circumstance of running under root privilege on Unix/Linux,  which should never actually apply.