# Will Windows notify in events of network up/down?

Tags: windows, networking

i am writing a c program. I need to detect if network goes down?
Is there any notifier that notifies network up/down events? If so how should i listen for such notifications?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Notification of when a network interface is ready on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546878/notification-of-when-a-network-interface-is-ready-on-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the old SO [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546878/notification-of-when-a-network-interface-is-ready-on-windows?rq=1) about interfaces becoming available.

I believe you should be able to use [`NotifyAddrChange()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366329%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for this. It's worth noting that this is on interface level so it might be that you have one interface going down while another becomes available (e.g. Moving from Wifi to wired network).